# Why do we treat differential notation as a fraction in u-substitution method

Tags: integration

How did we come to know that treating the differential notation as a fraction will help us in finding the integral. And how  do we know about its validity?

How can $\frac{dy}{dx}$ be treated as a fraction?

I want to know about how did u-substitution come about and why is the differential treated as a fraction in it?

Comment: Integration by substitution is just the Chain Rule of differentiation put into practice. It works because the Chain Rule works. The differential is treated as a fraction because that works, too.

Comment: I want to state that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is _not_ a ratio and is _never_ treated as such--$\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator which means to differentiate with respect to $x$.  If instead you mean $\frac{dy}{dx}$ then you should edit your question to be more clear.  You can also realize the operator $d$, i.e. the differential of a function $f$: $df$ which might shed light on your problem.  As an example, when I taught Calculus and we dealt with solids of revolution, I always had my students write out: $dV = \pi r^2 dh$ (for washer problems) and always illustrate what $r$ and $dh$ were in the picture.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily need to be.

Consider a simple equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(2x+5)$ and let $u=2x+5$. Then
$$\frac{du}{dx}=2$$
Traditionally, you will complete the working by using $du=2\cdot dx$, but if we were to avoid this, you could instead continue with the integral:
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\sin(u)dx$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\sin(u)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dx$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sin(u)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}dx$$
$$y=c-\frac{1}{2}\cos(u)$$
$$y=c-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x+5)$$

But why is this? Can we prove that the usefulness of the differentiatals' sepertation is justified? As Gerry Myerson has mentioned, it's a direct consequence of the chain rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}dx$$
But then if you 'cancel', it becomes
$$\int\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int\frac{dy}{du}du$$
Which is what you desired.

Comment: In the second line with the integrals, where does the fraction $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?

Comment: @d56, It comes from derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=2$. That means that $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{1}{2}=1$, and we can safely multiply anything by $1$ without changing the result. So we strategically multiply by this expression with the $\frac{1}{2}$ to introduce the derivative into the integral.

Comment: Thanks, understood! But what still bugs me is that we treat the differential $\frac{du}{dx}$  as a fraction by cancelling the denominator with $dx$. I cannot understand why we do that...

Comment: @d56, The Integral here is true because of the chain rule:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x$$
However, the next integral below is not true because we "cancel out" on the RHS of the above, but rather because $x$ and $u$ are dummy variables: we are effectively just changing notation:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}u}\mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: So the final line of my answer is a tautology; it doesn't follow from the previous equation, but rather from a straightforward change in notation. The fact that this tautology is true, and also the chain rule is true, means that if you use both equations together, it _looks like_ cancellation, even though algebraically the thing going on is not actually cancellation at all (well, at least not at this high-level view of things.) Hopefully that makes things clear.